# How to call setState function onClick ES6 way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
class BlogPost extends React.Component{
    //getInitialState
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.onLike = this.onLike.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            like :0
        }
    }

    onLike(){
        this.setState({
            like: this.state.like++ 
        });
    }

    render(){
        var postListItem = this.props.postList.map(function(post){
            return <li><a href="#"> {post}</a> </li>
        });
        return (
            <div className="blogPost">
                <h2>Posts</h2>
                <ul>{postListItem}</ul>
                <button onClick={(e) => {this.onLike}}>{this.state.like}</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Nothing happens on clicking `Button`.
There is no function on button and index.js has added Empty Function to it. IDK why?please explain

Comment: Try that snippet `<button onClick={(e) => {this.onLike()}}>{this.state.like}</button>`

Comment: @feeeper- if i do so, function will go in infinite recursion(i.e.) [until browser crashes], But my button works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you need remove arrow function (`(e) => { }`), it is not necessary here, because you bind `this` in `constructor`., also inside `onLike` change `this.state.like++` to `this.state.like + 1`  because you can't mutate state

```
<button onClick={ this.onLike }>{this.state.like}</button>
```

```js
class BlogPost extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.onLike = this.onLike.bind(this);
    
    this.state = {
      like: 0
    }
  }

  onLike(){
    this.setState({
      like: this.state.like + 1 
    });
  }

  render(){
    var postListItem = this.props.postList.map(function(post){
      return <li><a href="#"> {post}</a> </li>
    });
      
    return (
      <div className="blogPost">
        <h2>Posts</h2>
        <ul>{ postListItem }</ul>
        <button onClick={ this.onLike }>{this.state.like}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<BlogPost postList={ [] } />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not invoking the `onLike` function in the annonymous function you're passing to `onClick`.

Try this:

```
<button onClick={(e) => {this.onLike()}}>{this.state.like}</button>
```

Note the `()` after onLike.

Comment: after adding `( )` to the code, it goes into infinite recursion i.e until browser crashes, IMO it's because as setState updates itself to see any change in DOM and  function is in recursion state, my like in one second will be around 500, depending on my clock rate.

Comment: Yes, I would deffinitely avoid using that auto increment operator when setting the state, as the way `setState` works is not synchronus and it could be the source of your infinite recursion

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate